# bootstrap grid 4 column and 3 columns same width align center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: bootstrap grid]

Is there anyway to achieve the column below using bootstrap?
I tried but it wont align to the center

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10598/

thankssss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is supported by all browsers:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    width:400px;
    //margin: 10px;
}
.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom;50px;
}
.row2 {margin-left:30px;}
.row div{margin-right:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**OR**

You can use bootstrap's `pull-left` class like this:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    width:400px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.row2 {margin-left:30px !important; margin-top:5px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left col-md-offset-1">
          <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
          <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
          <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/l2d2eyolf/box.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @clement i am glad i could help